# Find method of excel vba in activated workbook

Tags: excel, vba, find

all hints that I find concerning search functionality in vba-excel refers to the same workbook. However, after activating another workbook, like in this snippet of code

```
aDifferentWorkbook.Activate
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:=LookedFor.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

the result is always 
    Found Is Nothing = True
although LookedFor.Text is present in this workbook. 
Does anyone know if there are special rules after switching to a different workbook?

Thank you very much
DevEd

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually select a worksheet within that workbook:

```
aDifferentWorkbook.Activate 'optional
aDifferentWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
Set Found = Cells.Find(What:=LookedFor.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Then select the next sheet and so on.

Slightly cuter code is

```
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each ws In aDifferentWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set Found = ws.Cells.Find(What:=LookedFor.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Next ws
```

as it avoids any selection

Comment: Thank you, perfect. I thought, I was close to the solution, but it seemed to me illogical that the search worked across worksheets within the very same workbook, but not in a foreign one.